# How to access data of another firebase project

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I created real time database on firebase, from one android app im sending data and in other app(second separate app different from the app im using for send data, for just retriving if there is change in data) i want to receive that data, how can i do this, because if I'm trying to access like this in onCreate

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);

DatabaseReference data = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference("https://my-project.firebaseio.com/nodeName");
```

I'm getting first initialzeApp also i tried with adding google-service.json from my app that sending data, its saying that its different from project name, how can i do that the firebase structure is like this

```
{ https://my-project.xxxx somenumbers
    {
        node{
               lat : "value"
               lng : "value"
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: is your data updating on firebase console from your app or not?
and by other app did you mean the same app in other device or actually any other app?

Comment: Yes its updated on console, by other app means anyother app

Comment: The other apps can access the same database only if they are added in same Project at Firebase console.

Comment: Just updated my question, actually im unable to make reference to firebase database so that i can call listener on it

Comment: Could you elaborate? Because i understand that if rules of database is write and read all means no authentication then we can just reference that database and start listening to it without adding or anything, m i right?

Comment: these rules mean that any user can read or write data without authentication process , but using all apps of the same project. Otherwise without authentication you can't read database regardless of you are using the same app or not.

Comment: Could you answer

Comment: What do you mean by all apps

Comment: There is an option to add multiple apps in the same project at Firebase console.

Comment: Yes it is, suppose if im adding new app, the name would be different and all the things, still i will be able to access data of other app in the same project?

Comment: Yes, because at the end your app belongs to the the same project on firebase console and .json file will identify that.

Comment: Json file is registered with the first app,

Comment: you don't worry about that , each app gets a json file.

Comment: So i shoud go through all the setup for second app too?

Comment: I'm able to get reference to node, like this DatabaseReference data = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance() .getReference("latlng").child("lat"); how can I get value at lat, updated my question for database structure

Comment: could you answer so i can accept this

Answer (score 3):

For every Android app that you create in Android Studio that you want to use with a specific Firebase project, you should create an Android app in the Firebase console too. You can do this by going to the [overview page of your project](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/overview) and clicking "Add another app".

Comment: Thanks, I'm able to get reference to node, like this DatabaseReference data = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference("latlng").child("lat");   how can I get value at lat

Comment: That seems like a different problem. But before posting it, I recommend first reading a few [existing questions about the Firebase Database](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-database%5D+%5Bandroid%5D+read+value), read [the relevant documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events) and maybe take the [codelab for Android](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/).

Answer (score 0):

In Firebase console there is option to add multiple apps in the same project. All applications that belong to same project can access same Firebase database. Each app has its own .json file connected with same project. So, if you want to access database from any other app then you need to connect that app with the same Firebase project at the console. And to get the values, make a reference to node and apply value change listener to it. [Official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) will help you

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be **like this**

```
DatabaseReference otherDB_data = FirebaseDatabase
.getInstance("https://my-project.firebaseio.com/nodeName")
            .getReference();
```

**instead of**

```
DatabaseReference otherDB_data = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference("https://my-project.firebaseio.com/nodeName");
```

and Don't forget to `authenticate` in your app to get realtime database access

> Note: Authenticating is useless if Realtime Database Rules are like

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth == null",
    ".write": "auth == null"
  }
}
```

so everyone already have the permission

> You can do this as many times as you like, but you can only have one
>   connection to any given database instance at once.

Source : [Firebase Documentation - Connect your app to multiple database instances](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/sharding#connect_your_app_to_multiple_database_instances)

Comment: But will this work if "my-project.firebaseio.com" is from one firebase-project and the android app is in another firebase-project?

Comment: @rehman_00001 But you need to **give up** on *that* database's authentication as I know and that's not good since anyone would be able to access it (*have the permission*) as I said in this post. It's been a long time since I used Firebase so I really don't know much if they fixed this problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @X Stylish. that helps!!